# Groupby mysql show different record when sorting used

Tags: mysql, group-by

when i run query with below sql

```
SELECT 
userproduct_id,product_id,offer_price
FROM `tbluserproducts`
WHERE `product_id` = '4722'
ORDER BY `offer_price` asc
```

it show result like this

```
userproduct_id  product_id  offer_price
4848            4722        1200
4835            4722        12500
4837            4722        12500
4841            4722        17000
```

and when added groupby product_id in above sql

```
SELECT 
userproduct_id,product_id,offer_price
FROM `tbluserproducts`
WHERE `product_id` = '4722'
group by product_id
ORDER BY `offer_price` asc
```

it shows only one record

```
userproduct_id  product_id  offer_price
4835            4722        12500
```

but it don't show userproduct_id `4848` record because  i am ordering by `offer price asc`

my structure of the table is below

```
Column          Type                 
userproduct_id  int(10) unsigned Auto Increment 
product_id      int(11) unsigned    
offer_price     decimal(30,0)
```

Comment: Any columns in a `GROUP BY` query which are not aggregated or in the `GROUP BY` clause will take random values regardless of any `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Nick, not _random_ rows, because it's repeatable. It's basically the _first_ row MySQL reads in the group, by index order. But this is implementation-dependent and there's no guarantee of it.

Comment: @Nick how to aggregated

Comment: @BillKarwin can you give me a better term i.e. one word that means the value you get is random but you'll get the same value every time you try it?

Comment: @Pritamkumar functions like `SUM`, `COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX` etc.

Comment: @Nick, I use the term _arbitrary_. MySQL chooses the row for its own convenience, not for any logic in your query.

Comment: @BillKarwin yeah, good word for it. Too late to edit that comment but I'll use that in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use GROUP BY the query returns one row for product_id 4722. If there are multiple rows in the group, MySQL chooses one row from that set of rows.

How does it choose the row?

It must read the rows in some order, and it chooses the first row it reads. It reads the rows in PRIMARY KEY order in this query, so it shows the row with the least `userproduct_id`.

The `ORDER BY` you give applies *after* the `GROUP BY` reduces the output to one row, so it's sorting a set of one row, and that has no effect.

---

I think you want to return the row that has the least `offer_price`, right? You could have made that more clear in your question.

This is basically the same type of problem that has been asked on Stack Overflow hundreds of times. The tag [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) is used for this general type of problem.

In your query, you're only selecting one product_id, so it would be easy to use LIMIT to return only the first row.

```
SELECT 
  userproduct_id, product_id, offer_price
FROM `tbluserproducts`
WHERE `product_id` = '4722'
ORDER BY `offer_price` asc
LIMIT 1
```

If you want many product_id's, and the row with the lowest `offer_price` for each one, it's a bit more complex. In MySQL 8.0, you can use a windowing function:

```
WITH ranked_userproducts AS (
  SELECT 
    userproduct_id, product_id, offer_price,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY offer_price) AS rownum
  FROM `tbluserproducts`
)
SELECT 
  userproduct_id, product_id, offer_price
FROM ranked_userproducts
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

In MySQL 5.x, you can try another method:

```
SELECT 
  userproduct_id, product_id, offer_price
FROM `tbluserproducts` AS p1
JOIN (
  SELECT product_id, MIN(offer_price) AS offer_price
  GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY NULL
) AS p2
  ON p1.product_id = p2.product_id AND p1.offer_price = p2.offer_price;
```

There might be other solutions too. I recommend you follow the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag and read some other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
    SELECT 
    userproduct_id,product_id,offer_price
    FROM `tbluserproducts`
    WHERE `product_id` = '4722' and userproduct_id=(select max(userproduct_id)
from `tbluserproducts` b where b.`product_id` = '4722')
```

Comment: i used your query it shows record like this
`userproduct_id product_id offer_price
4848 4722 1200
4835 4722 12500
4837 4722 12500
4841 4722 17000`

Comment: @Pritamkumar, like what?

Comment: @Pritamkumar, what is your expected output then?

Comment: `userproduct_id  product_id  offer_price`                                                                      
`4848            4722        1200`

Comment: thanks you solved my query i tried with this it worked
`SELECT 
    userproduct_id,product_id,offer_price
    FROM tbluserproducts
    WHERE product_id = '4722' and offer_price=(select min(offer_price)
from tbluserproducts b where b.product_id = '4722')`